# HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out when trying to read a reddit comments post

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2, reddit, http-status-code-504

I am encountering an error when trying to get a comments' http from reddit. This has happened to various URLs (not all of them with special characters) and this is one of them. In one hour time frame, there may be 1000 or more requests to the reddit.com domain.

```
hdr = {"User-Agent": "My Agent"}
try:
     req = urllib2.Request("http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/"
           "comments/1bjuee/when_pokΓ©mon_was_good", headers=hdr)
     htmlSource = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
except Exception as inst:
     print inst

Output>>HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out
```

Comment: What makes you think that it's code and not network error? And what is the actual question? Do you need explanation why it's not working, or solution/workaround for it?

Comment: First of all I would like to know, why it is not working. The code is given so the problem can be replicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTTP Error 504 Gateway timeout](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E504.html) - A server (not necessarily a Web server) is acting as a gateway or proxy to fulfil the request by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) to access the requested URL. This server did not receive a timely response from an upstream server it accessed to deal with your HTTP request.

This usually means that the upstream server is down (no response to the gateway/proxy), rather than that the upstream server and the gateway/proxy do not agree on the protocol for exchanging data.

Problem can appear in different places on the network and there is no "unique" solution for it. You will have to investigative the problem by your own.

Your code works fine. Possible solution for you problem would be:

```
import urllib2
hdr = {"User-Agent": "My Agent"}

while True:
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request("http://www.reddit.com/", headers=hdr)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        htmlSource = response.read()
        if response.getcode() == 200:
            break
    except Exception as inst:
        print inst
```

This code will try to request webpage until it gets 200 response (standard response for successful HTTP requests). When 200 response will occur while loop will break and you can do next request (or whatever you have in your program)

Comment: What changing DNS servers help mitigation this issue? I tried adding Google dns 8.8.8.8 to my /etc/resolve.conf but I'm still seeing them. Its for a well known web site.