# How to resolve 'HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out'

Tags: python, urllib2, urlopen, http-status-code-504

I am gettiing a HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out when I am running urllib2.urlopen and don't know how to resolve this.

I tried referencing this link: [HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out when trying to read a reddit comments post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786421/http-error-504-gateway-time-out-when-trying-to-read-a-reddit-comments-post) but solution was no successful.

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req_body = {
'query:' query,
'variables': {
    'product': product
}
}
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(req_body))
print 'opened'
```

I know this format is correct because I have used it in the past and it worked. I am expecting 'opened' to be printed, but I get the 504 error and the code exits.